# Limit of function involving natural logarithm

Tags: limits

I was wondering why the limit of the following function is:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\dfrac{\ln x}{x}} = -\infty $$

When we try to solve the limit by substituting in 0, one would expect the numerator to go to minus infinity and the denominator to 0. Thus, having an indeterminate form as a quotient, we could apply L'Hôpitals Rule. But then we would get:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\dfrac{1}{x}} = +\infty $$
What's wrong with what I've written above? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Recall that indeterminants are of forms such as $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$. In a hand-wavey way, $\ln0/0=\infty/0$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck You mean $- \infty$, right?

Comment: @Ramanujan Yes, but the signs of the terms do not matter in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that what you get is *not* an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). In order to apply L'Hopital, you need "$\frac{0}{0}$" or "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$", or [other forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form) that are in the assumptions of the [L'Hopital rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form).  Your limit is none of these forms.

To see why   $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{\dfrac{\ln x}{x}} = -\infty $, follow the definition.

Given any $M>0$, let $\delta=\min(\frac1e,\frac1M)$. Then
$
0<x<\delta$ implies that

$$
\frac{1}{x}>M,\quad \ln(x)<-1
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\ln(x)}{x}<-M
$$

Comment: That’s right. But then, how would you justify the limits is minus infinity.

Comment: @Rainbow: see edits.

Comment: In addition to the indeterminate forms 0/0 and infinity/infinity, L'Hospital's rule is applicable when the denominator tends to infinity irrespective of the numerator. Of course here denominator doesn't tend to infinity (it tends to zero) and hence not applicable.

Comment: Yes. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that using Taylor expansions you have

\begin{align}
   \ln x &= \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, dt = \int_0^{x - 1} \frac{1}{1 + u} \, du \\
   &= \int_0^{x - 1} (1 - u + u^2 - u^3 + \cdots) \, du \\
   &= (x - 1) - \frac{(x - 1)^2}{2} + \frac{(x - 1)^3}{3} - \frac{(x - 1)^4}{4} + \cdots \\
   &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1} (x-1)^k}{k}=(x-1)+\dotsb.
 \end{align}

Hence $\ln x \approx x-1$ (first order) and

$$\frac{\ln x}{x}\approx \frac{x-1}{x}=1-\frac{1}{x}\overset{x\to 0^+}{\to} -\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

In the interval (0 1), log x is negative and x is positive. Hence the negative ratio tends to - $\infty$